# Add form fields dynamically in .net 6 MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I am new to .net mvc and working on a small app.

I have a Model-driven form. I would like to add or remove fields dynamically to it. I have tried to find some solution but cannot find a concise and good way to do it.
Can someone please point me in right direction.

The screenshot is as follows

[image]

The Index.cshtml is as follows.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Daily Report";
}
@model MyApp.Models.DailyReport
    <div class="contents">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="submissionDate" class="col-4 col-form-label">Date</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input id="submissionDate" name="submissionDate" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" readonly value="@Model.submissionDate">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="topicsCovered" class="col-4 col-form-label">Topics Covered</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="topicsCovered" name="topicsCovered" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="topicsCoveredHelpBlock" required="required">@Model.topicsCovered</textarea>
                    <span id="topicsCoveredHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the topics covered</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="allocatedHomeWork" class="col-4 col-form-label">Assigned Homework</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="allocatedHomeWork" name="allocatedHomeWork" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="allocatedHomeWorkHelpBlock" required="required">@Model.allocatedHomeWork</textarea>
                    <span id="allocatedHomeWorkHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">What homework was assigned?</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="generalSummary" class="col-4 col-form-label">General Summary</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea id="generalSummary" name="generalSummary" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="generalSummaryHelpBlock" required="required">@Model.generalSummary</textarea>
                    <span id="generalSummaryHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Feedback for today</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4"></div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="studentsContainerHeader">
                                <h4>Students</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddStudent", "EditDailyReport")'; return false;"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tbody>
                                    @if (Model.students != null)
                                        {
                                        @foreach (Student student in Model.students)
                                            {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="studentContainer">
                                                        <div class="student">
                                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                                <label for="fName" class="col-4 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                                    <input id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="Student's First Name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="@student.fName">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                                <label for="lastName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                                    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Student' Last Name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="@student.lName">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                                <label for="remarks" class="col-4 col-form-label">Remarks</label>
                                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                                    <textarea id="remarks" name="remarks" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" aria-describedby="remarksHelpBlock">@student.remarks</textarea>
                                                                    <span id="remarksHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Any remarks for student</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="deleteStudentBtnContainer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RemoveStudent", "EditDailyReport", new { id = student.id })'; return false;"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-minus"></i></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            }
                                        }

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and the controller is as follow.

```
public class EditDailyReportController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IReportsRepository _reportsRepository;
        private readonly ILogger<EditDailyReportController> _logger;

        public EditDailyReportController(
            ILogger<EditDailyReportController> logger,
            IReportsRepository reportsRepository
        ) {
            _logger = logger;
            _reportsRepository = reportsRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int reportId)
        {
            DailyReport report = new DailyReport();
            if (reportId != null && reportId > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    report = await _reportsRepository.GetDailyReportById(reportId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            return View(report);
        }

        public async void AddStudent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Student Id: ");
        }

        public IActionResult RemoveStudent(int id) {
            Console.WriteLine("Remove Student Id: " + id);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```